# Selecting iloc based on a condition

Tags: python, indexing, subset

My problem is quite hard to explain but easily understandable with an example :

From this dataframe

`pd.DataFrame([[2,"1523974569"],[3,"3214569871"],[0,"9384927512"]])`

I would like to obtain :

```
pd.DataFrame(["15","321",""])
```

It means that the first column is telling me how much characters I should extract from the second column starting from the start.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you could get it using `apply` and `lambda` on dataframe as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,"1523974569"],[3,"3214569871"],[0,"9384927512"]])
df[2] = df.apply(lambda x : x[1][:x[0]], axis=1)
df
```

it will give you the output

```
    0   1           2
0   2   1523974569  15
1   3   3214569871  321
2   0   9384927512
```